# Download failed because you may not have purchased this app - emulator

Tags: download, apk, licensing, apk-expansion-files

Dears,
My apk expansion is working fine with real devices, but with emulator I get this error

```
Download failed because you may not have purchased this app
```

This is the logcat:

> BE/Checking_download:  expansion not delivered
>   E/Checking_download:  try intent
>   E/Checking_download:  intented launched
>   E/Checking_download:  Category isandroid.intent.category.LAUNCHER
>   E/Checking_download: Start the download service
>   E/Checking_download: initialize activity to show progress , result is: 2
>   ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
>
> ```
> [ 04-25 00:08:50.630  8167: 8167 D/         ]
> ```
>
> HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x9f4b1d40, tid 8167
>    E/Checking_download: service_resume :

```
                  [ 04-25 00:08:50.828  8167: 8190 D/         ]
                  HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa1fdf2c0, tid 8190
```

> E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008cdf
>   E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008824
>   E/Checking_download: service_to_connected : 
>   E/Checking_download: service_connected : 
>   E/FA: Discarding data. Failed to send app launch
>   E/FA: Failed to get app instance id
>   E/FA: Failed to send current screen to service
>   E/FA: Discarding data. Failed to send event to service
>   E/Checking_download: DownloadStateChanged : Looking for resources to download
>   E/Checking_download: DownloadStateChanged : Download failed because you may not have purchased this app

Notes:

1-Again app live on google play working fine with real devices.

2-Emulator API version is : google play API-25.

3-Google account is added to emulator. ( logged in with my gmail).

4-Google play services installed.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Android emulator & Genymotion give same error

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer is very simple, the application version code must be same like uploaded version to google play.
i.e ( in build.gradle, app level check

> versionCode 2

Then you have to confirm from google play that this version is already uploaded and life.